# Can't insert date into any HTML element

Tags: jquery, html, date

All I am trying to do is insert today's date into a TD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var myDate = new Date();
    $(myDate).appendTo("#calcShptable td:first");
    });
</script>
```

Just doesn't do anything.. no errors or anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var myDate = new Date();
    ("#calcShptable td:first").append(myDate.toString());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your value and your element selector reversed. Try

```
$('#calcShptable td:first').append(myDate.toString()); // Append text, not appendTo()
```

Comment: This would attempt to append the element to the date string... you would need to use `append` if you wanted it this way round.

Comment: `appendTo()` takes a selector as taget! http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/ - You mean `append()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just insert a string like it was a node.  Make it into a node first:

```
$(document.createTextNode(myDate)).appendTo("#calcShptable td:first");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4xcG/

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! This one was just easiest for me

Answer (score 0):

You've created a date object and what you want to do is create a date string like this:

```
var today  = new Date(),
    myDate = today.getDate() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getFullYear();
$("#calcShptable td:first").append('<span>' + myDate + '</span>');
```

Here is a link to some documentation for the JavaScript Date Object (you can create a date in any format you like): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: that's odd... I didn't see the span in there before.